# Is the Maurer-form a 1-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am studying Lie groups and lie algebras following Nakahara book. In 5.6.4 he introduces the concept of Maurer-Cartan one-form in this way:
\begin{equation}
\theta: X \rightarrow {(L_{g})^{-1}} _{*} X
\end{equation}
where X in a vector of $T_{g}G$. So $\theta$ acts as a map from

\begin{equation}
\theta: T_{g}G \rightarrow T_{e}G
\end{equation}
So it acts on a vector and associates to it the corresponding vector in the Lie algebra. I don't understand why it is called a one form, since I know that a one form should act on a vector and produce a number, not another vector. I don't know if it is just a matter of "names" or if I'm missing something.

Comment: It is just a matter of names, the Maurer-Cartan form is a "vector-valued" one-form.

Comment: So using standard definitions it should be a 1-1 tensor, right?

Comment: If you use the identification $\operatorname{Hom}(T_gG,T_eG)\cong T_gG^*\otimes T_eG$ (which holds true for finite-dimensional vector spaces), then somehow the answer is yes although a (1,1) tensor the way I know it is an element of $V^*\otimes V\cong \mathrm{End}(V)$ for some fixed finite-dimensional vector space $V$.

Comment: Normally, a $1$-form $\theta$ on $G$ defines, for each $g \in G$, a linear function $\theta(g): T_gG \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. However, if $blah$ is a vector space, then we say that $\Theta$ is a $blah$-valued $1$-form if, for each $g \in G$, it defines a linear map $\Theta(g): T_pG \rightarrow blah$. Here, the Maurer-Cartan form $\theta$ defines for each $g \in G$, a linear map $\theta(g): T_p \rightarrow T_eG$, so it defines a $T_eG$-valued $1$-form.

Comment: @Explosiveness No that is not a $(1,1)$-tensor. As frog says that refers to an element of $V^*\otimes V$ or (commonly in Physics) to a tensor field i.e. a section of $T^*M \otimes TM$. While that looks similar at first glance to what you have it is not the same. $TG$ is a vector bundle but $T_eG = \mathfrak{g}$ is a fixed vector space. So $\theta \in \Gamma(T^*G \otimes \mathfrak{g})$ rather than  $\Gamma(T^*G \otimes TG)$.

Comment: Have a look at the [Wiki page on vector valued forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-valued_differential_form)